# IE9 <section> does not reflect 100% correctly

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9, width

In IE9 [This Page](http://www.torontoclubscene.com/clubaudits/view/17/intro) element `section#tcs-website-content` shows 990px width with CSS `width: 100%` where all parent elements have width of 100% thus having browser width which is 1024px

I have no experience with IE9 whatsoever, so I don't know what is the problem I need to look at.

CSS (LESS) for the elements:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'muliregular','oswaldregular',Arial;
}

#viewport {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: none;
}

#tcs-website-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 120px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    #bundle .box-sizing();

    & .inner-content {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure it covers the whole width, I would add the following definition to `#tcs-website-content`:

```
right: 0;
```

Comment: I did this immediately after I posted the question and it worked... :D